# How to show fields of a model in django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, model

Suppose I have a situation where I input a field from user and depending upon the field I have to query the corresponding model.

Say if the user enters rice then I have to query on rice model. Also  there are many models where each models have different number of fields.

What I want is to return a list containing `n` number of dictionary where `n` is the number of fields in that model. Say if I have username and age fields in student model then I want to return `[{"username":"Sagar"},{"age":21}]`.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this.

Comment: It does not look like a good idea to use `[{"username":"Sagar"},{"age":21}]` over `{"username":"Sagar", "age":21}`. A single dictionary looks more appropriate since it is easy to query.

Comment: you can try something like <model_queryset>.values(*<model_fields>), where somewhere in your code you map model_name inputs to the queryset and fields you desire

Comment: what you're looking for is .values()